# how will windows schduler react if i have Console.ReadLine(); inside my console application

Tags: c#, cmd, console-application, windows-server-2008-r2, taskscheduler

I wrote the following as part of my c# console application. currently when i run this inside Visual studio or i run the .exe file manually , the command prompt will show a message, and the user need to click on any key to exist the window.

```
  Console.Write(syncResult + " Press any key to exsit..");
  Console.ReadLine();
```

now i want to call this console application from windows task scheduler,, so not sure if this mean that the command prompt will stay active ? i mean the .exe will keep running when a windows task call the .exe on pre-defined interval.?

Thanks

Comment: The task will not complete until someone presses enter. Why would you leave that in when you're running as a scheduled task?

Comment: @KenWhite just incase some one need to run it manually..not sure what is the best way to manage this..

Comment: You should add a commandline parameter. Such as `/q`uiet.

Comment: So make it accept a command line switch, which the service will receive and running it manually does not. You can then detect if it's being manually started and call `ReadLine` only then.

Comment: @johnG out of curiosity - why would a person need to manually exit the application? are there outputs you want to show them?

Comment: @johnG If they need to run it manually and see the output they should run in a command window instead of by double clicking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have several tools like this running on production servers and dealt in all those cases the way people have suggested already. I have a command line argument like /q (quiet) or /u (unattended) that is checked before calling Readline:

```
if (!args.Any(a => a == "/q"))
  Console.ReadLine();
```

Otherwise the Task will not complete execution and a few days later you will find **lots** of them still running in TaskManager. Of course when creating the task you have to remember to add that parameter in the config.